# Matlab & HDF5: Written string attributes have b'string' format

Tags: matlab, types, attributes, hdf5

I'm using hdf5 structure with string attributes. I usually wrote the data in python and had no problems. Now i need to write the same structure from matlab.

For attributes I'm using h5writeatt(), e.g.:

```
h5writeatt(filepath, dataset, 'myattr', 'mystringvalue');
```

When I'm reading the attribute from python with h5py all attributes return in the format

value = b'mystringvalue'

Any ideas why matlab uses this format and how to disable it? I'm doing string comparison which fails ofc since the b and the ' are part of the string. Of course writing a small function to check for this format and remove it is not that difficult but seems unnecessary overhead.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

`b'foo'` is the representation of a Python [byte sequence object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview), not a string.

Strings in Python 3.x are [a different data type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) which is a sequence of Unicode code points, not bytes, so that Python (unlike MATLAB) can properly handle text in multiple languages.

If you compare a byte sequence to a string they are not the same:

```
>>> s = 'foo'
>>> b = bytes([102, 111, 111])
>>> b
b'foo'
>>> s == b
False
```

To be able to compare them you need to either `encode` the string to a bytes object, or `decode` the bytes object to a string:

```
>>> s.encode('ascii') == b
True
>>> s == b.decode('ascii')
True
```

Note that you have to specify what encoding you want to use to translate between strings and bytes. `ascii` will always convert one code point to one byte and vice versa but will raise an error if it meets a byte value greater than 127 - if you need to use these characters then you'll need to decide which code page you are using and specify a [suitable codec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) instead. This is the sort of headache that Unicode was invented to do away with, of course.